# confusion about limits

Tags: limits

you have lim when x aproaches infinity of (x*(1/x)). Its very easy u just have to cut the x after multiplying (x/x) and it ll be 1 of course. I went to one of those limits solver online and there is a rule that states that lim(xy)=limx limy so i was just messing around i asked myself if we could join limits. So i went to search for counterexamples cuz one exercise was wrong because i joined limits. So keep in mind this: lim(xy)=limx limy. lim when x aproaches infinity of (x(1/x)) is 1 as demonstrated above. But if i go to the online limit solver and put lim(x)lim(1/x) i get 0 instead of 1. If lim(xy)=limxlimy then why lim when x aproaches infinity of (x*(1/x)) doesnt equal lim(x) lim(1/x)?. How is that even 0? Pls answer. And answer why we cant join 2 limits into one if so why the property is lim(xy)=limxlimy and not lim(xy)=>limx*limy.

Comment: $(\lim x_n)(\lim y_n) = \lim x_ny_n$ only applies when the left side's limits exist and are *finite*. If one of them doesn't exist or is infinite then that rule does not apply and you have to check the convergence or divergence of the product $x_ny_n$ in some other way. Though if one of the limits is finite *non-zero* and the other is infinite then the product does also tend to one of the infinities.

Comment: The identity $\lim_{t\to a}f(t)g(t)=\left(\lim_{t\to a}f(t)\right)\left(\lim_{t\to a}g(t)\right)$ is usually meant to hold under the hypothesis that $\lim_{t\to a}f(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to a}g(t)$ exist **in** $\Bbb R$; at a large, the identity can be extended to hold when these limits exist in $[-\infty,\infty]$ and $$\left(\lim_{t\to a}f(t),\lim_{t\to a}g(t)\right)\notin\{(-\infty,0),(\infty,0),(0,-\infty),(0,\infty)\}$$ Setting a multiplication on $[-\infty,\infty]^2$ such that $0\times\infty=0$ isn't an unreasonable convention, but that doesn't change the validity of the theorem.

Comment: so let me confirm. You can join limits under the condition that they are finite. Then how would you calculate that one limit: lim(x)* lim(1/x)? just for curiosity. Also thx for answering so quicky.